# React-Router Rerendering with Immutable shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, react-router

I have got a problem with rerendering the component, when I switch to a different route and then back to my component.
I am using React 0.14.3, react-router 1.0.2 and Immutable.js.

The reason is, that I compare props in my `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !Immutable.is(nextProps.articles, this.props.articles);
}
```

If I change the route and go back, `props.articles` does not change, but I need to rerender the page anyways.

The question is, what do I need to consider in my `shouldComponentUpdate` method, to track, if the route has just changed?

Thanks in advance!
Rico

Comment: Haven't you tried? I suspect that you don't need to care about that since when you change the route your component will be re-mounted.

Comment: My component is displaying a table of data. That data comes from an API and is stored in "articles". The route leading to that component is /articles.
When I switch the the route / and then back to /articles, the component does not update, since the articles are the same as before. If I comment out my shouldComponentUpdate, it works.

TL;DR - I tried, it did not work.

Comment: Well, your shouldComponentUpdate shouldn't even be called when you go back to the /articles. Because it isn't updating, it's mounting, componentDidMount is called.

Comment: For instance, here are folks trying to solve the opposite problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431319/prevent-component-be-unmounted-with-react-router
In other words, what you're trying to achieve is react router's default behavior.